# Can waitFor() be used with a graphical external editor?

Tags: java, process

My issue is that my program launches an external editor (currently hard coded to sublime), I want the program to wait for the user to type everything they want in the external editor, save it, and then on **exit** continue the original program. I thought creating a process and using `waitFor()` would be perfect to use here, but the original program opens the editor and then continues like it never needed to stop? I'm not sure if this has something to do with the fact the process I'm launching is an external editor or some error I've made coding it. I looked for an alternative solution, but it doesn't seem to work either. I'll post both:

```
try{
                theText.setText(cti.initialText);
                String currentText = theText.getText();
                File temp = File.createTempFile("tempfile",".tmp");
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
                bw.write(currentText);
                bw.close();
                say("START IT");
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("subl " +
                temp.getAbsolutePath());
                try{ 
                    p.waitFor()
                }catch(InterruptedException exc) {

                }
                say("DONE");
      }
```

I also tried this, to no avail:

```
BufferedReader stdOut = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String s;
                while((s=stdOut.readLine()) !=null){

                }
```

Should `ProcessBuilder` be used to do this? If so, I would love an example to work from. Please let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: `Process#waitFor` will only wait until your external program starts then it returns.

Comment: Is sublime starting through a shell that exits when the GUI had launched?

Comment: @matthelliwell yes i usually have both a shell and sublime already running when trying this out. I figured each tab in sublime/the shell would be a separate process?